# NetSuite: Linking Inventory to Sales Order Items

Tags: netsuite

NetSuite:
In our environment all our items are special order items or drop ship items. So if an item is in the inventory, it will have a sales order to go with it.

We need the following report created:

Location, Item, Qty, Amount, SO#, Customer Name

How does one walk form items in the inventory at a given location and get to sales order?

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

Unless an item is a lot/serialized item there is no built-in distinguishing characteristic that would allow you to link an item to a sales order. The item record is a template for a fungible item.

Drop Ship item should never be in inventory unless you accept returns on behalf of your vendor. By definition a drop ship item is shipped from your vendor to your customer.

Special order items are generally not in your inventory very long unless an order was cancelled after the PO was issued to the item's vendor. (or if you restock returns)

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

Drop Ship item: Good point and yes agree.

Special Order item: Agree. However, given logistics of receiving all vendor products on a SO in a timely fashion, we end up with items in our inventory for longer than we would like to. 

With that said, is it possible to link an item in inventory to a PO and then walk the PO to an SO?